# Dates show up wrong using free-hand SQL

Tags: business-objects

I am using Business Objects 4.2. I have a query in SQL that I am trying to put into BOBJ using free-hand SQL, but the dates show up as 1 day behind.

For example, when I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio, it shows '9-1-2016', but the report in BOBJ is showing '8-30-2016'

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Could it be that in one there is a `<` or `>`, and in the other `<=` or `>=`?

Comment: I am using freehand SQL to select "@Prompt('Date (dd/mm/yyyy):','D',,mono,free)" and choosing tomorrow's date and it is returning today's date.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the correct dates by converting the object from a "Dimension" to a "Detail" as per a colleague's guidance, however I do not understand the specifics of why this error was happening in the first place or why this fix works.